Set Tailwind Base Layer Styles for Subset of Components
I would like to apply styles on html elements of a subset of a website (documentation part of the website) but don't like to apply those styles on the rest of the site.
The problem I'm facing is: Either I can style the whole website with the base layer, or I'm using the component layer and cannot override the styles with tailwind utilities beacause the css score is too high (class + element vs. utility class).
(tailwindcss 3.3, nextjs 14.1)
base layer - only complete website
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  p {
    @apply font-light text-lg leading-8 my-4;
  }
}

OR: component layer - css score too high
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .documentation {
    p {
      @apply font-light text-lg leading-8 my-4;
    }
  }
}

